# Special character problem when get data using JavaScript

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

When the name in the database has special character like user.name it will generate this error:

```
  Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: .chat[data-user-id = jquery.min.js:2 user.name]
```

or has space like "user name"

```
Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: .chat[data-user-id = jquery.min.js:2  user name]
```

But if the name in the database has not special character like "." or space it works.

I use data-user-id to get user

```
    $('.app-chat .chat-users').on('click','.chat-user', function(event) {
        var findChat = $(this).attr('data-user-id');
        $('.chat[data-user-id = '+findChat+']').addClass('active-chat');
}
```

Comment: dont use space when selecting a selctor try

`$('.chat[data-user-id="'+findChat+'"]').addClass('active-chat');`

Comment: You are missing a closing  `)` in your click function as well.

Comment: BTW. Instead of $(this).attr('data-user-id') you could write $(this).data('user-id')

Comment: you have huggedintax error... can you check your code again plz, problem is not related with php or javascript, problem is your missing syntax annotation..